# customvalidator always isvalid=true

Tags: datetime, date-range, custom-validators

I have a custom validator for checking if date enetred is valid. but it is always true that makes it not firing. I used to have a comaprevalidator and daterange but it won't work coz as page refreshes, it validates the date of birth and says invalid when it is. So I changed it to customvalidator hoping I will find luck.

```
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter MM/DD/YYYY format. Invalid Date 01/01/1901 to 12/31/9999" 
                                                            ControlToValidate="txtAccusedDOB" SetFocusOnError="True" ClientValidationFunction="ServerValidation1" Display="Static">
                                                        <asp:Image ID="Image125" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/validatearrow.png" />
                                                        </asp:CustomValidator>
                                                        <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender  
                                                        runat="Server"  ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender5"  TargetControlID="CustomValidator1" Width="250px"  HighlightCssClass="highlight"  
                                                          CssClass="CustomCalloutStyle"  PopupPosition="Right" WarningIconImageUrl="~/images/001_11.png"
                                                        CloseImageUrl="~/images/001_05.png" />
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccusedDOB" runat="server" Style="text-transform: uppercase" onkeydown="TrapEnterKey()"
                                                            Width="70px" TabIndex="85">
                                                        </asp:TextBox>
```

here's the java script. it always shows the alert("test" + arguments.Value.toString()); The try catch is not working.

```
function ServerValidation1(source, arguments)
   {
   try{

        var x= new Date();
        x = Date.parse(arguments.Value.toString())
         arguments.IsValid = true;
         alert("test" + arguments.Value.toString());
    }
    catch(Error r)
    {

     arguments.IsValid = false;
      alert("test OUt" + r.toString());
    }
```

is there a simpler way to check if date entered is valid. I have been struggling on this for days already. thanks.